# Cannot call Remote MySQL database using SSH tunneling

Tags: mysql, ssh-tunnel

I have two system where one system has the MySQL database (IP address is 192.168.0.149-running in centos) and the other has the web application (IP address 192.168.0.55-running in windows). I am calling the database from the web application remotely. I wanted to use ssh to connect with the database, so I use putty to do this.

First I run the putty and initiate the port forwarding from port 3535 to 192.168.0.149:3306.

I call from my application like this

```
orm.RegisterDataBase("default", "mysql", "john:john1@tcp(127.0.0.1:3535)/employee?
charset=utf8&parseTime=True")
```

I create a user in host MySQL database like this

```
mysql>create user john
mysql>GRANT CREATE,DELETE,SELECT,UPDATE ON employee.* TO 'rahul'@'192.168.0.55' IDENTIFIED 
BY 'john1'
```

Now I run my web application. When I run it I'm getting the following error

```
 [ORM]2017/03/01 16:18:57 register db Ping `default`, Error 1045: Access denied for user 
'john'@'192.168.0.149' (using password: YES)
```

> WORKING SCENARIOS

If I don't use the SSH and calling directly the database from the application then there is no problem for this  user to access the employee database.

```
   orm.RegisterDataBase("default", "mysql", "john:john1@tcp(192.168.0.149:3306)/employee?
    charset=utf8&parseTime=True")
```

2. If I change the privilege condition like this then its working for ssh based remote database connection

   ```
   sql>GRANT CREATE,DELETE,UPDATE,SELECT ON employee.* TO 'john'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'john1'
   ```

But I don't want to do this since it will accept the connection from all the system from the local network.I wanted to give the access to only 192.168.0.55.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your credentials don't match.

You've granted access to `'rahul'@'192.168.0.55'`, but you're connecting as `'john'@'192.168.0.149'`.

Try granting access to the user that's actually connecting:

```
GRANT CREATE,DELETE,SELECT,UPDATE ON employee.* TO 'john'@'192.168.0.149' IDENTIFIED BY 'john1'
```